# Django MEDIA_URL não está funcionando

Tags: django, static

Até ontem estava funcionando tranquilamente a rota `/media/` em DEV, e fui fazer um deploy pra produção e um dump da produção para meu ambiente para igualar, e começou a dar esse problema. Tive também que juntar novas funcionalidades de diversas branchs, então aconteceu algo que não estou conseguindo identificar. Atualmente minhas configurações estão dessa forma:

urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "public")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)
```

Porém recebo um 302 toda vez que carrego uma imagem ou arquivo que está no media. E pior, ela redireciona para a rota principal `/`

```
[23/Aug/2017 14:55:35] "GET /media/product/teste.png HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/Aug/2017 14:55:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16764
```

Comment: Seu ambiente de produção é o mesmo de DEV? Digo, ambos rodam LINUX/Windows?

Comment: Cara eu resolvi meu problema, era uma cagadinha que fiz em uma rota que criei para trabalhar com paginas estáticas. Ela estava sobrescrevendo todas as outras rotas haha. Vou fechar a pergunta. Obrigado